# The tangent bundle over a manifold is trivial iff the manifold is paralelizable

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Why is the tangent bundle over a manifold trivial if and only if the manifold is parallelizable?

What additional condition do we need to impose on a fiber bundle if we want it to be trivial exactly when it has $n$ nowhere vanishing smooth sections, where $n$ is a given natural number?

Comment: Looking at your questions I have seen that you have asked many questions today. I would like to tell you that there is a limit to the number of questions that can be posted.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the first part:

Because if it's parallelizable, you can find a global frame field of the manifold $M$> This frame field induces a bundle isomorphism to $M\times\mathbb{R}^n$ covering the identity on $M$. Conversely, if the tangent bundle is trivial, then a trivialization is a global frame field.

Comment: Thank you, Neal. Would you specify the said isomorphism.

Comment: Would you point out a paralelization on a trivial bundle.

Comment: @Student $(p,e_i)\in M\times\mathbb{R}^n$, $i=1,...,n$, where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.